# Can't eat food or shoot arrows in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I can't eat or shoot arrows in Minecraft!
I tried restarting the game, new minecraft.jar or relogging in. When I right click when I am holding food/bow with arrows, it doesn't do anything! 
Hunger is getting low!

Comment: Can you place blocks?

Comment: I have voted to close this because you have not supplied much information. Tell us what "use item" is bound to, if you even have any arrows in your inventory, if you can place blocks, etc.

Comment: @jeffreylin_ this has only been posted an hour, and it appears to be his/her first post. Don't get to excited give them time to change.

Comment: @Paralytic oh, oops. Sorry about that, seemed like a question with not enough details. Didn't pay attention to the asker.

Comment: check your controls, and see what the "use item" is set to

Comment: @Paralytic There's nothing wrong with closing a question quickly if there's not enough information provided.  It'll just get get guesses as answers, otherwise.  Once the extra information has been provided, we can re-open.

Comment: @fbueckert closing this question is wrong, putting it "on hold" till it is fixed is right.

Comment: @Paralytic They amount to the exact same thing.  It's just a word change.

Comment: @fbueckert [nope](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/06/the-war-of-the-closes/?cb=1)

Comment: @Paralytic [yes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184154/closing-changes-on-hold-unclear-too-broad-opinion-based-off-topic-reasons) - just a wording change. "On Hold" is what is formally known as "Closed".

Comment: I have the same eating problem in MineCraft 1.9+ on Mineplex multiplayer.  It's a work around, but I have to hold down the eat button for a long time in combination with sneak (L-shift) and it finally works.  What's extremely odd, is I have reproduced it on Mac and PC, and 2 different users.  It's so annoying that I still mainly use v 1.8.9.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely, "Use Item" became unbound or bound to something else. Go to Options and then to Controls. Check what "Use Item" is, in the top-right.

[image: Use Item is the top-right-most button and is bound to Button 2 by default.]

By default it's bound to `Button 2` or the right-click button. If it isn't for you, you can left-click it and then right-click it to rebind it. It should work now.

If it was already set correctly or if setting it didn't help, then there's probably something wrong with your mouse.